# Extract the text from webpage

Tags: php

In this [test.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/test.php) page i have this line of text

> server=span.growler.ro&provider=-1&providersSerial=4&country=RO&mobile=0&token=eae5b2c50c123425d9351d8c8ee80b9a27ca3d69f15a669454b937eb

in this other  [test1.php?id=token](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/test.php) page i have this php code runing

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("./test.php"); 
if(isset($_GET["id"])){ $id = $_GET["id"]; 
$regex = "/".$id."=\'([^\']+)\'/"; 
preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match); 
$fid=$Match[1][0]; 
echo $fid; } else { echo ""; } ?>
```

i need only the token

> eae5b2c50c123425d9351d8c8ee80b9a27ca3d69f15a669454b937eb

to be show on test1.php?id=token

if in test.php the token looks like this

> token='eae5b2c50c123425d9351d8c8ee80b9a27ca3d69f15a669454b937eb'

it works.

i needet to work from onother web page

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'server=span.growler.ro&provider=-1&providersSerial=4&country=RO&mobile=0&token=eae5b2c50c123425d9351d8c8ee80b9a27ca3d69f15a669454b937eb';
parse_str($str, $vars);
$token = $vars['token'];
```

Comment: this is not correct usage. it must be `parse_str($str, $output); $token = $output['token'];`

Answer (score 0):

using with preg_match will help you .

```
$string ='server=span.growler.ro&provider=-1&providersSerial=4&country=RO&mobile=0&token=eae5b2c50c123425d9351d8c8ee80b9a27ca3d69f15a669454b937eb';
preg_match('/token=([a-f0-9]+)/i',$string,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

this will return you :

```
'eae5b2c50c123425d9351d8c8ee80b9a27ca3d69f15a669454b937eb'
```

Comment: the string is changing evri time  i need to take only token as is changing from that page

Comment: this will work with strings like : evrything+token=evryhash+evrything  :: and will return you "evryhash"

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) instead of preg_match_all

Try this regex:

```
$regex = "/&?token=([a-f0-9]*)&?/;
```